# Using "completely" to start a sentence

Tags: adverbs, sentence-starts

Is it proper to start a sentence with completely? As in,

> Completely, the men trusted her.

Why or why not?

I ask because it doesn't "sound" right.

Comment: It's a little weird, but it could work in the right context.

Comment: Completely submerged now, the raft slipped from their grasp. Only the lifejackets kept them afloat. It was a dark and stormy night, etc.

Comment: "Completely believing him was a mistake." Yes, it works, though the usage is rare.

Comment: It can work, but almost always next to the verb it is modifying, not set off on its own by a comma. That is my feeling as well.

Comment: A friend posted an article about sentence adverbs that seems to answer my question.
"Whereas an adverb typically modifies the verb of a sentence, a sentence adverb is an adverb that appears usually at the beginning of a sentence and modifies the sentence as a whole. This type of adverb usually ends in –ly and is often followed by a comma."